# Bluej OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory, bluej

I wrote a java program in Bluej and ran it for small values (100000). But for larger bound (1000000) I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. How can I solve it in Bluej? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class prob
{
    private static final int N = 1000000;//5000000
    private static final int h = Math.min(N, (int)(Math.cbrt(0.5*N*N)));;
    private static byte[][] small;
    private static int[] smallSums;
    private static int[] smallCounts;
    private static int periodCount;
    private static int periodSum;

    private static void recursiveInit(int x, int y, int steps, int h)
    {
        if (x <= h)
        {
            for (int z = x + y; z <= 2*h; z += x)
                recursiveInit(z, x, steps + 1, h);
        }
        else if (x <= h + y)
        {
            small[y][x - h - 1] = (byte)steps;
        }
    }

    private static long recurseRule(int a, int b, int c, int d, int steps, int limit, int y)
    {
        int i = c;
        int j = d;
        long sum = 0;
        for (;;)
        {
            i += a;
            j += b;
            if (i*(h + 1) + j*y > limit) break; 
            int xmax = (limit - j*y)/i - (h + 1);
            int k = xmax%y;
            long cnt = smallCounts[k] + (xmax/y)*periodCount;
            long s = smallSums  [k] + (xmax/y)*periodSum;
            sum += cnt*steps + 2*s + recurseRule(i, j, a, b, steps + 2, limit, y);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        smallCounts = new int[h];
        smallSums = new int[h];
        small = new byte[h + 1][];
        for (int y = 1; y <= h; ++y) small[y] = new byte[y];
        for (int x = 2; x <= 2*h; ++x) recursiveInit(x, 1, 1, h);
        long sum = N;
        for (int y = 1; y <= h && y <= N; ++y)
        {
            smallSums[0] = small[y][0];
            smallCounts[0] = 0;
            if (small[y][0] != 0) ++smallCounts[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < y; ++i)
            {
                smallSums[i] = smallSums[i - 1] + small[y][i];
                smallCounts[i] = smallCounts[i - 1];
                if (small[y][i] != 0) ++smallCounts[i];
            }
            periodCount = smallCounts[y - 1];
            periodSum = smallSums[y - 1];
            int f = (h + 1)/y + 1;
            for (int gmax = N/y; gmax > 0;)
            {
                int r = N/gmax;
                int gmin = N/(r + 1);
                int i1 = (y + y*f) - (h + 1);
                int i2 = (r + y*f) - (h + 1);
                int j1 = i1%y;
                int j2 = i2%y;
                int k = i2/y - i1/y;
                int s = smallSums  [j2] - smallSums  [j1] + k*periodSum;
                int c = smallCounts[j2] - smallCounts[j1] + k*periodCount;
                sum += (gmax - gmin)*(2L*s + c + recurseRule(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, r, y));
                gmax = gmin;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is "+sum);
        double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time elapsed : "+(end-start)/1000d+" seconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know what code you're running to tell you how to fix it to begin with...could you provide code so we could ask, "What are you doing with this snippet?"

Comment: When asking questions, please provide a specific example of what you're trying to achieve and also what you've currently done. In its current state, your question can't really be answered and may be closed. To learn more about asking great questions, see How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: since there is this public demand , would you please post some of your code

Comment: So, now your question is indeed answerable.  Thanks for posting your code.

Answer (score 0):

As per the http://www.bluej.org/help/faq.html#jvmargs page

Windows: use the bluej.windows.vm.args property in bluej.defs

Linux/Unix/equivalent: edit the "bluej" shell script which is created by the installer (in the directory where you installed BlueJ), and modify the last line (which launches BlueJ).

**Update**

As noted by Makato, this problem you are facing indicates that potentially something is wrong with your program as it does not seem to be using memory efficiently.  Please post a snippet.

**Update**
You code looks OK

Comment: No.  Something *else* is wrong.  Something much deeper.  Something that requires looking at code.

Comment: @Makoto I am not trying to guess the OP code.  Maybe it is doing exactly what she wants, and she is honestly just troubled by lack of heap space.

Comment: But we don't know that for certain.  I truly think that something else is wrong - if it were a user that had a code base with high memory usage, they'd know by now how to increase the virtual memory (and, I would *seriously doubt* that they would use BlueJ as their IDE of choice).

Comment: @Makoto I have updated my answer to reflect your concern - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but there isn't a correct answer 
go to the bluej.defs file and add

bluej.vm.args= -Xmx2G or any amount

note ^ windows isn't there

also you may have to change the JVM that bluej is using because the default is 32bit which can cause some issue you can do this by renaming the jdk folder in the bluej folder to jdk-32 or anything else so that it will ask you what jdk you want to use on startup select a 64bit one

Answer (score -1):

try to run java with higher ram using Windows Commands Processor with

`javaw -Xmx2048 -Xms1024 -jar your_jar_file_name.jar`

So basically, the `xmx` is your maximum RAM your allocating and your `xms` is the minimum ram it should use.

Comment: This more masks the problem than actually fixes it.  Without context of code, we can't really say or not say that this is the definitive answer.

Comment: Maybe his program use ton of memory. So try to run java with higher ram should fix it. And also " Without context of code, _we_ can't really say or not say that this is the definitive answer. –  Makoto" we? it is only YOU

Comment: My argument is simple:  we *don't know* what's causing the high memory usage.  Yes, your fix takes care of the **immediate** pain, but that doesn't mean that it won't crop up later down the road.  It also doesn't mean that we've formally "solved" the problem, either.  Just because it can be solved like this doesn't mean it's appropriate, ***especially*** when we haven't seen the actual **cause** of the high memory usage.

Comment: His application really need a high memory to run so what we can only do is allow more ram to the application.